# Duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 : soomla issue

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, soomla

I got this error after reimporting the soomla package.
How to solve this?

duplicate symbol _NewBase64Encode_soomla in:
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Soomla/libSoomlaiOSCore.a(NSData-Base64.o)
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/SoomlaShared/libKeeva.a(NSData-Base64.o)
duplicate symbol _NewBase64Decode_soomla in:
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Soomla/libSoomlaiOSCore.a(NSData-Base64.o)
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/SoomlaShared/libKeeva.a(NSData-Base64.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBEncryptorAES in:
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Soomla/libSoomlaiOSCore.a(FBEncryptorAES.o)
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/SoomlaShared/libKeeva.a(FBEncryptorAES.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBEncryptorAES in:
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Soomla/libSoomlaiOSCore.a(FBEncryptorAES.o)
    /Users/Nikunj/Unity/2D/NoOneCanDoIt/Build/b2/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/SoomlaShared/libKeeva.a(FBEncryptorAES.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Showing first 200 warnings only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `libKeeva` and `libSoomlaiOSCore` contain the same functions and classes (symbols). You need to exclude one of these libraries or rebuilt one of them not using conflicting symbols (or make it depend on another library).

Another variant is to include one of the libraries to your project as source code.

UPD: it seems like `libSoomlaiOSCore` and `libKeeva` is simply two versions of Soomla, so you can just delete one of them.